# preg_replace of "Word" in a sentence and "Word." on the end of a sentence

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i want to preg_replace "Word" in PHP.

```
    $ret = 'I gave my Word to you.';    
    $pattern = '/\bWord\b/i';
    $ret = preg_replace($pattern,"Heart",$ret);
// echo $ret; = "I gave my Heart to you";
```

This works so far. But if the sentence is "I gave you my Word." or "I gave you my Word!" it doesn't change the "Word." into "Heart."

Comment: [Works fine](http://www.ideone.com/lAiI7).

Comment: If it's such a simple replacement perhaps `str_replace` is faster than the regular expression.

Comment: @Fanis: `str_replace` won't detect word boundaries.

Comment: @KennyTM you're absolutely right, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is. works for me.

```
<?
    $ret = 'I gave my Word to you Word.';
    $pattern = '/\bWord\b/i';
    $ret = preg_replace($pattern,"Heart",$ret);
    var_dump($ret);
?>
```

string(29) "I gave my Heart to you Heart."

Comment: To add to this, \b word boundaries matches words with [a-zA-Z0-9_] characters.

Comment: Hmm, when i put this in a single php file it works, in my other code not. maybe the problem is in some other code. thanks so far for open my eyes